# How to debug EntityQuery?

Tags: 8, database, entities

I have a query with a 'BETWEEN' operator and I should have some results. Is there any way to show the actual SQL query made ?

Here is my entity query :

```
    $query = $this->entity_query->get('node');
    $query->condition('type', 'store');
    $query->condition('status', 1);
    if ($lat_min && $lng_min && is_numeric($lat_min) && is_numeric($lng_min) && $lat_max && $lng_max && is_numeric($lat_max) && is_numeric($lng_max)) {
      $query->condition('field_store_geolocation.lat', [$lat_min, $lat_max], 'BETWEEN');
      $query->condition('field_store_geolocation.lng', [$lng_min, $lng_max], 'BETWEEN');
    }
    $nids = $query->execute();
```

Of course I made sure that my values were the one expected and I also tried with '<', '>' and with no vars but actual values to make sure nothing was wrong there.

I'm using the '[Geolocation Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation)' module here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you use devel module a simple approach for debugging entity query could be use the `debug` tag (simply add `$query->addTag('debug')` to your query).
Here an example

```
$query = $this->entity_query->get('node');
$query->condition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED);
$query->addTag('debug');
$query->execute();
```

And the result

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! For some reason I had tried that and nothing showed up but I could eventually see it by visiting an other page :-) Thanks a lot !

Comment: For the anonymous user it's not working, how can I give the access?

Comment: @RajeshVishwakarma enable devel for anonymous